# UIPickerView without objects

Tags: uipickerview

I have a picker with one array, this array sometimes don't have objects inside, this is ok, but when the picker is shown and is scrolled the app crash.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Don't show UIPickerview if the array is empty. At least it will stay empty or crush your app.

Comment: Also it's hard to give you some wise advise. First of all have to know the logic of your app.

Comment: Show the picker is necessary, alternative solution i have is

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if(_arrPicker.count==0){
        pickerView.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    }
    return _arrPicker.count;
}

Comment: Just hide it if arr is empty.

Comment: if arr is empty, then change it with some default arr like "one dummy string - No Data".

Comment: Don't ask any questions without code. It's right way to downvotes in this community.

Comment: Yeah, another simple solution.

Comment: Ok. Exchange the arr with other single string arr - "No Options".